# Firewall management on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, soa, firewall

I am creating a SOA application and I would like to separate out logic in multiple OpenShift applications. The problem is, that some of the applications aren't supposed to be accessible from the internet -- only private services are going to use them.

I would like to allow access to those applications only from specific domains (lets say appB-domain.rhcloud.com and appC-domain.rhcloud.com). Is it possible to do that somehow on OS/OpenShift (like firewall rules and I haven't found about them in the docs)? Or must I do that in application level?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do that at the application level.  There are no firewall rules that you can change, for instance, you can not update iptables.

Comment: By any chance, is this feature planned to be implemented some day? :-)

Comment: Not that I am aware of.